# Utilisation du passé simple au quotidien

Tags: grammaire, oral, passé-composé, passé-simple

J'étudie la langue française par moi-même et j'utilise Internet pour mon apprentissage. Je crois que je suis de niveau A1. Depuis que j'ai commencé, j'ai appris le passé simple. J'ai lu qu'à l'oral, ce temps n'était pas utilisé. Ma langue maternelle est l'espagnol, et le passé simple, le passé composé ainsi que l'imparfait sont fréquemment utilisés au quotidien alors quand je parle, le passé simple me vient en tête et je ressens le besoin de l'utiliser comme je le fais en espagnol. Par exemple, je ne dis pas :

- En 1965 mon père a travaillé dans une grande entreprise.

mais je dis :

- En 1965 mon père travailla dans une grande entreprise.

J'aimerais savoir, si je parle en utilisant le passé simple, est-ce bizarre ? Puis-je l'utiliser sans problème ? Les autres penseraient-ils que je veux être prétentieux ?

Excusez-moi si j'ai fait quelques (ou plusieurs) erreurs de grammaire.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. À en juger sur la rédaction de ta question tu es plutôt de niveau A2 -B1 en expression écrite. Je te conseille le site [Bonjour de France] pour la grammaire. Le passé simple [1](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/14/grammaire/179.html) et [2](http://www.bonjourdefrance.com/exercices/contenu/14/grammaire/178.html). Je sais que le passé simple est beaucoup plus employé en espagnol qu'en français. Voir [ici](http://www.espagnolfacile.com/exercices/exercice-espagnol-2/exercice-espagnol-42332.php).

Comment: Comme Laure le dit, le texte est de niveau bien supérieur à A1. Si j'exagère un peu, le niveau A1 consiste à savoir dire "bonjour", "aurevoir" et "merci"... là, les phrases sont proches de la réalité et sont tout à fait compréhensibles, même si elles contiennent quelques fautes pardonnables :)

Comment: @Random Oui tu exagères un peu, A1 on fait quand même des phrases **simples**. [En raccourci.](https://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/fr/resources/european-language-levels-cefr). Si  jecarfor veut se tester en ligne: http://www.testsdefrancais.com/. Mais le meilleur outil pour tester son niveau de langue c'est Dialang, à installer sur PC, gratuit. Je le recommande. Permet de se tester en 14 langues européennes - toutes les compétences sauf l'expression orale.

Comment: Félicitations pour votre message vraiment bien écrit. Oui, utiliser le passé simple à l'oral fait bizarre voire prétentieux si ça vient d'un francophone, mais venant d'un étranger ce sera amusant ou même impressionnant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Effectivement, le passé simple n'est pour ainsi dire **jamais** utilisé à l'oral. Même dans les oraux professionnels ou très formels, on emploie le passé composé ou l'imparfait. De nos jours, on utilise le passé simple **seulement dans un cadre narratif** par exemple dans des romans ou des poèmes ; donc 99% du temps à l'écrit.

Le seul cas où on pourrait utiliser le passé simple à l'oral sans que cela semble bizarre serait pour **raconter une histoire** ou **lire un texte narratif à voix haute**.

En utilisant le passé simple à l'oral, vous n'auriez pas l'air prétentieux mais simplement étranger ;)

Pour votre exemple, je dirais :

> En 1956, mon père a travaillé dans une grande entreprise

Ou, si il y a travaillé pendant quelques temps :

> En 1956, mon père travaillait dans une grande entreprise.

Comment: L'utilisation de "pour ainsi dire" est quelque peu osée pour un niveau A2-B1 non ? :)

Comment: @Random À mon avis, ce n'est pas de tout osée; l'OP a exprimé que sa langue maternelle est l'espagnol. Il arrive qu'en espagnol l'expression est  la même: "por así decir(lo)".

Comment: @Random Je me suis en effet demandé si je devais utiliser une autre expression quand j'ai écrit mon message mais je me suis dit qu'être confronté à des expressions de ce style be pourrait qu'être bénéfique pour l'apprentissage de la langue (je pense avoir été assez claire dans le reste de mon message pour que l'OP puisse tout de même comprendre) :)

Comment: @NicholasJ. Merci pour cette information de culture générale :) Ne parlant pas un mot d'espagnol ce n'était là qu'un coup de chance !

Comment: Merci @Ctouw, j'ai compris votre explication, je pense que je dois pratiquer pour m'habituer à utiliser le passé composé chaque fois que je ressens le besoin d'utiliser le passé simple.

Answer (score 5):

Félicitations pour avoir écrit l'intégralité du message en français !

Le passé simple est aujourd'hui d'usage quasi-nul dans le vocabulaire parlé. Si vous voulez parler français incognito, il vaut donc mieux utiliser le **passé composé**.

Si vous souhaitez savoir la réaction des gens si vous utilisez ce temps, et bien ils seront la plupart du temps très étonnés, et certains pourraient même ne pas vous comprendre !

Et pour cause, ce temps est assez difficile

> *nous parûmes, vous pourchassâtes, tu trouvas*...

Je vous **recommande fortement** d'apprendre le *passé composé*

> *nous avons paru, vous avez pourchassé, tu as trouvé*...

et de revenir à ce temps lorsque vous aurez fait vos armes !

Comment: Je dirais même qu'une grande partie des natifs ne savent pas comment conjuguer un verbe au passé simple... !