# Passé simple, when to use?

Tags: passé-simple

A few weeks ago, I learned what the 'passé simple' is, but I really don't understand when you have to use it. So, I did some research: according to multiple sources, it is used in books, you can change it to the 'passé composé'. But, is that the only way you can use it. If so, why would you only use it in books, as an abbreviation?

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of pointing people to past questions, but this is one of those things that's been asked many times. A quick search for "passe simple" at top right gives you some questions to start with, and if those still leave you confused (even after just skimming them), return here. :)

Comment: Three answers on FL already answer your question. What else exactly do you want to know ? What does "as an abbreviation" mean in your question? I do not understand what using a tense as an abbreviation mean. [Utilisation du passé simple au quotidien](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/19790/358), [Why is the passé simple not used in spoken French?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/8208/358), [Différence entre le passé simple et le passé composé](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/9/358),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le passé simple, dû à la complexité de son apprentissage, est un temps qui est désormais très **peu utilisé à l'oral**. L'utilisation du passé simple donne désormais une consonance romancée à une phrase. Personne ne parle au passé simple, ça aurait l'air bizarre, voire [*hautain*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/_hautain_hautaine/39212).

Cependant, il est encore enseigné à l'école en français, et encore **courant dans les livres**.

> Un  dimanche,  ils  se  **mirent** en  marche  dès  le  matin,  ils
>   **vagabondèrent** entre  les vignes,  **arrachèrent** des coquelicots au bord des champs,  **dormirent** sur l’herbe.
>
> *- Bouvard et Pécuchet*, Gustave Flaubert

Comment: En quoi le passé simple est-il plus complexe qu'un autre temps ? Serait-il possible de montrer quels nouveaux éléments cette réponse apporte à celles faites aux [10 questions déjà étiquetées passé simple](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pass%c3%a9-simple)sur FL?

Answer (score -1):

To summarise, the *passé simple* is an archaic form that has lost its uses along the years. A few centuries ago, it was used as a common past tense, similar to the simple past in English, but it was progressively replaced in everyday speech by the *passé composé* and the *imparfait*.

No living French speaker has ever used the *passé simple* in a normal conversation, except for some archaical/comical effect, or in very few idioms where the *passé simple* structure has been fossilised (e.g., « Il **fut** un temps »).

This said, yes, it is used in literature (novels, [fairy] tales...), only written thus, to narrate a sequence of events. It is thus strictly restricted to this specific literary (narrative) written form. For instance, it is extremely unlikely to see it in written correspondence, even very formal, or in essays. So, unless you are planning on writing literature in French, you simply do not need to use it, only to understand it in your reading.

Comment: Much more thorough answers have already been given on FL on the usage of passé simple. Stack Exchange sites [do not favour duplicates](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) questions and answers in order to favour canonical answers.

Comment: Désolé pour cette erreur. Mais le vote négatif me semble quand même un peu fort : au moment où j'ai répondu, la question n'était pas marquée comme 'duplicata' et la plupart des questions-réponses antérieures étaient en français. Il me semblait qu'une réponse brève en anglais pouvait avoir un intérêt. Dans tous les cas, félicitations pour [votre réponse antérieure](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8208/why-is-the-passé-simple-not-used-in-spoken-french) (qui me paraitrait plus adéquate comme renvoi ci-dessus d'ailleurs [_This question already has an answer here_]).

Comment: Il me semble que ce message s'adresse à moi, alors je tiens à préciser que je n'ai pas mis de vote négatif à cette réponse (ni de vote positif non plus). Mon commentaire n'était qu'une information et ne signalait aucune erreur factuelle.

Comment: @Laure OK, merci pour la clarification. Nous sommes d'accord donc :)