# temps qui peut remplacer le passé simple en français parlé

Tags: grammaire

Bonjour,

En français écrit, on pourrait lire : " Il courut aussi vite qu'il put ", par exemple dans un conte de fées que je lis à un enfant, supposons maintenant que je raconte l'histoire avec mes mots à moi pour qu'il comprenne mieux , normalement, je vais utiliser le passé composé et l'imparfait ( si je n'utilise pas le présent historique), alors, quels sont les temps que je vais employer ? J'ai tendance à dire : " il a couru aussi vite qu'il pouvait .." mais  cela voudrait dire que dans certains cas, on peut aussi remplacer le passé simple par l'imparfait ? ou faudrait-il dire : ".....qu'il a pu ?"

Je vous remercie d'avance et vous souhaite une bonne journée.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Utilisation du passé simple au quotidien](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19790/utilisation-du-pass%c3%a9-simple-au-quotidien)

Comment: A Laure : je suis désolé, je ne comprends pas en quoi mon message serait une copie ( duplicate ???)  d'un ancien post intitulé : " utilisation du passé simple au quotidien " , de toute façon, je n'y ai pas trouvé de lien avec ma question qui reste toujours sans réponse.

Comment: À mon avis les deux réponses à la question expliquent comment remplacer le passé simple par le passé composé ou l'imparfait et la différence entre les deux. Mais peut-être que ce n'est pas suffisant ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Les deux possibilités seraient acceptables selon ce que je peux déduire mais le passé composé serait préférable. Les explications suivantes tendent à confirmer cela.

Si on se base sur cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aussi+vite+qu%27il+a+pu%2Caussi+vite+qu%27il+pouvait&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caussi%20vite%20qu%27il%20a%20pu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caussi%20vite%20qu%27il%20pouvait%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Caussi%20vite%20qu'il%20a%20pu%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caussi%20vite%20qu'il%20pouvait%3B%2Cc0) les deux possibilités sont correctes ; cependant on s'aperçoit en examinant les livres que le passé composé est utilisé après un verbe dans la principale qui est aussi au passé composé et que l'imparfait est utilisé après un verbe dans la principale qui est soit au passé simple soit à l'imparfait (une exception, passé composé) soit au subjonctif ou bien après un participe présent ou un gérondif.

En utilisant le passé composé on insiste sur les possibilités de courir qui sont celles du moment : il a couru aussi vite qu'il le pouvait à ce moment précis lorsqu'il a couru. Si on utilise l'imparfait il n'existe plus cette certitude qu'il s'agit des possibilités du moment mais on n'est pas sûr, on ne devient sûr que ce sont des possibilités indépendantes du moment que si l'on ajoute un complément;

- Il a couru aussi vite qu'il (le) pouvait (le faire) dans des moments de frousse intense. *Il est préférable d'ajouter soit le pronom « le » soit la locution « le faire »*.
- <s>Il a couru aussi vite qu'il a pu  dans des moments de frousse intense.</s>
- <s>Il a couru aussi vite qu'il a pu le faire dans des moments de frousse intense.</s> *Ces deux dernières constructions n'expriment pas l'idée voulue, elles ne communiquent rien de défini.*

Dans l'usage de l'imparfait il existe une ambiguïté entre une situation habituelle et une situation particulière. On s'aperçoit peut-être de cela dans la comparaison des deux phrase ci-dessous;

- Bien que la douleur ait été forte il a couru aussi vite qu'il pouvait.
- <s>Bien que la douleur ait été forte il a couru aussi vite qu'il a pu.</s> *Le temps ne convient plus, on obtient du non-sens ; si l'on accepte cette première phrase comme significative, on doit reconnaitre que le temps communique un état de chose qui est indépendant du moment : « qu'il le pouvait d'habitude ». Sans le complément qui rend la situation de la course particulière (Bien que la douleur soit forte) la phrase a de nouveau du sens.*

Lorsque la situation n'est pas rendue particulière vis-à-vis de l'action il n'y a pas de  différence importante ;

- Il a couru aussi vite qu'il a pu.
- Il a couru aussi vite qu'il (le) pouvait (le faire).

Comment: De tout ce qui précède, je peux donc conclure que , dans certains cas, le passé simple peut être remplacé par l'imparfait dans la langue parlée.

Comment: @prinver Oui, c'est ce que je crois, il ne semble pas y avoir de véritable différence ; on trouve de nombreux exemples de cela [ici](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/francais-anglais/aussi+vite+qu%27il+le+pouvait) et on voit que le verbe de la principale peut être l'imparfait, le passé composé, et le passé simple.